# Relocate the SBT target/ directory (compiled classes) to ramdisk/temporary directory

Tags: scala, sbt

In a given SBT project's `target/` directory, can occur quite a fair amount of disk I/O.

Given the use of an SSD (Solid State Drive), or maybe even to just improve compilation performance when I/O is slow, it may become desirable to relocate the target directory to a ramdisk such as `/tmp`.

Ideally, this would be a user-global setting specified in `~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt` so that the project-specific settings are not bound to the specific developer's set-up.

**How can I relocate the `target/` directory to another location in the filesystem, ideally including automatic sub-directories for projects to prevent conflicts?**

I found the following:

```
target <<= (name) { file("/tmp/sbt/") / _ }
```

on a [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/zA8slvMd8x4), but this seems to use the outdated `<<=` operator, and I can't figure out how I can rewrite this using modern syntax.

Answer (score 3):

How you can make a setting depend on another setting is described [in the official documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Task-Graph.html#Declaring+dependency+to+other+tasks). In your case it could look like this:

```
target := file("/tmp/sbt") / name.value
```